# Win 7, IDLE suddenly not working, Labview not working, system slow

Tags: python, performance, windows-7, python-idle, labview

I'm a little bit puzzled here right now.

I have Win7 64bit with Python 3.4.3 and LabVIEW 2015 installed. Out of the blue the system became very slow and two problems in particular arose. I can not use Idle any more (IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection...) and LabView is sort of reacting, but to slow to be used and crashing all the time. Firewall and Antivirus are turned of and I'm totally out of idea what could cause this. The system defnetily has enough power for what I'm doing and already successfully did:
Fujistsu c740 workstation
Xeon 6 core E5-1650 v3
32Gb ram
SSD
etc
I installed Tortoise svn and updated git, except that I did not install anything new or change any settings. After some googleing I found out that in msconfig->Boot/>Advanced Options-> Number of Processors was set to 1. I changed it to 12, but this did not help.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: If there were only a problem with IDLE, I would suggest the following: try the different ways of starting IDLE.  Use the Start Menu icon; right-click a .py file and select Edit with IDLE; enter `python -m idlelib` in Command Prompt console.  Do all three fail the same?  Does the console display an additional error message?

Comment: All three methods of starting Idle just pop up the same error message. Unfortunately

Comment: It was the Sophos AntiVirus/Firewall. Though everything was turned off it still was blocking something. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

When looking for an area to investigate for a murky problem, I typically start with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), which is a developer's Task Manager.

In addition to viewing the overall CPU/Memory/Disk/IO load, you can also slice those measurements by individual processes. The tool even goes further to show all of the threads in that process as well as their call stacks. In addition, it can find open DLL and file handles.